# Using readAllBytes to read a file's bytes, but output is not changing when I change the file

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte

If I have a directory called "files" and I have 2 txt files in there. The files have different names, but have the same exact contents. With this code, I am not getting the same byte[] when I readAllBytes. Should I be getting the same output when I print bytes? If not, what method could I use to compare byte strands in this way? I am trying to do this: if I have 2 files with content *in common* but not all the same, in this case, should I have commonalities in the two byte strands also? What method would accomplish this?

```
public class Main {
    public static final File CWD = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    public static final File files = new File(CWD, "files");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (File file: files.listFiles()){
            try {
                byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                System.out.println(bytes);
                System.out.println(file.toString());
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("File is empty");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print byte[] as a String which uses `String.valueOf(bytes)` and appears as something like: `[B@23ab930d` which is `[B` followed by the hashcode of the array. Hence different byte arrays have different string values. Compare these:

```
byte[]a=new byte[]{65};
System.out.println(new String(a));
=> A
System.out.println(a);
// Prints something like:
[B@6438a396
```

Change to print the byte array *contents* converted as a String:

```
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

OR: read the text file as a String directly:

```
String contents = Files.readString(file.toPath());
System.out.println(contents);
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. So what would I used if I wanted to compare strands of bytes within files (not necessarily txt files) ?